# Uncaught ReferenceError: firstFunc is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick Wordpress Divi

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, divi

Very new to the web development industry, and having some trouble figuring out what's wrong with my code. Trying to implement javascript onto a code snippet with Wordpress using Divi, but can't seem to understand what exactly is wrong. My intentions are to change the background & text color of the button on click. I'd appreciate the help!

```
<button onClick="firstFunc()";
 class="butCol";
 style="background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 2px 15px";>LATTES</button>

<script>
function firstFunc() {
 var x = document.getElementByClass("butCol");
  if (x.style.backgroundColor == "transparent";) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#373975"; 
    x.style.color = "white"};
  else {
    (x.style.backgroundColor = "transparent")
  };
};
</script>
```

Comment: as a side not, It would be easier to apply changes through CSS by using `classList.toggle()` which also makes it unecessary to write if/else-statements

Comment: Can I see the page directly? I sense it is the order of the element and script that is causing this.

Comment: There is no `getElementByClass` and install a linter in your IDE

Comment: Please avoid using inline styles and use `addEventListener` so that you can separate content, style and functionality. Better organized. Plus there are many syntax errors in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a few typos. unfortunately to many and to long to list them in the comments. So if this solve the issue for you, remove your question voluntarily:

1. `if (x.style.backgroundColor == "transparent";) {` -> remove the semicolon: `if (x.style.backgroundColor == "transparent") {`
2. `x.style.color = "white"};` -> swap the semicolon and clamp:  `x.style.color = "white"; }`
3. `(x.style.backgroundColor = "transparent")` -> remove the clamps and finish with a semicolon: `x.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";`
4. There is no `getElementByClass` just `getElementsByClassName`. However this would return an array. Just use `querySelector` instead.

```js
function firstFunc() {
 var x = document.querySelector(".butCol");
  if (x.style.backgroundColor == "transparent") {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "#373975"; 
    x.style.color = "white";
  } else {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  };
};
```

```html
<button onClick="firstFunc()";
 class="butCol";
 style="background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 2px 15px";>LATTES</button>
```

However, smarter would be to use CSS to apply the changes and just using the `.classList.toggle('class-name');` function:

```js
function firstFunc() {
 document.querySelector('.butCol').classList.toggle('clicked'); 
}
```

```css
.butCol {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
  
.clicked {
  background-color: #373975;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="firstFunc()";
 class="butCol";>LATTES</button>
```